# What type of data does a postgreSQL "SELECT" request return?

Tags: postgresql, select

I am wondering what kind of data is returned by a PostgreSQL database management system when performing a SELECT. [PostgreSQL documentation on SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html) mentions that the data return is an array. Yet we have to parse this information (in JSON, XML, whatever...) in order to be able to use it.

So I would like to know (by curiosity) what is the format of the "raw" data returned by PostgreSQL. Is it some kind of type specific to PosgreSQL? I have taken a look at the documentation, but I did not find anything.

Could anyone help ? :)

Comment: https://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/attachments/330_postgres-for-the-wire.pdf

Comment: PostgreSQL does not return a single object, but a set of rows. You access them with the function your API provides.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for your answer. So basically, from what I get, you first get a RowDescription, then one or several DataRows. And both are C structures.